# Clarification about the boot process (systemd / init)

Tags: systemd, init.d

I started disabling some services from systemd to speed up the boot time, but I noticed that many services are also in the old init (which runs). There are quite a few things that start in rc.d (or at least my script started when I placed it there originally).

My question is, why are some services in both places, and do I also have to remove them from rc.d ?

Comment: A minor clarification: It's not a matter of "systemd **vs** init".  Systemd **is** an [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) implementation, just as the SysV style init previously used was an implementation.  Both of them satisfy the requirements of the role with regard to the relationship to the OS kernel and responsibilities in userland.  I've edited your title to prevent further confusion ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's still `systemd` that handles the old-style init scripts, using [`systemd-sysv-generator`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/systemd-sysv-generator.8.en.html):

> systemd-sysv-generator is a generator that creates wrapper .service units for SysV init[1] scripts in /etc/init.d/* at boot and when configuration of the system manager is reloaded. This will allow systemd(1) to support them similarly to native units.
>
> LSB headers[2] in SysV init scripts are interpreted, and the ordering specified in the header is turned into dependencies between the generated unit and other units. The LSB facilities "$remote_fs", "$network", "$named", "$portmap", "$time" are supported and will be turned into dependencies on specific native systemd targets. See systemd.special(5) for more details.
>
> SysV runlevels have corresponding systemd targets (runlevel X.target). The wrapper unit that is generated will be wanted by those targets which correspond to runlevels for which the script is enabled.
>
> systemd does not support SysV scripts as part of early boot, so all wrapper units are ordered after basic.target.

Essentially, the documentation states that `systemd` generates unit files at startup for the services in `rc.d`, and uses the LSB headers to determine when the services should run.

In Jessie and Stretch, [LSB headers have been added](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/DependencyBasedBoot) to all old-style init scripts in `rc.d`, so these can continue to work despite the switch to systemd. As for why this is the case: [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/740832/398494) suggests that the plan was to have sysvinit as a fallback in Debian, and most likely for compatibility reasons also.

That said, there are some contradictions between the documentation, and what users have observed to actually be true. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/184220) on Unix & Linux claims that the headers are not required at all for systemd to convert them, which would explain why systemd still used your script, despite you probably not writing a perfectly LSB-compliant header.

You will need to remove the init scripts as you would with the old init daemon in order to stop these services from running too. See also: [disable init.d script in systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140534/disable-init-d-script-in-systemd) on Unix & Linux.

Comment: Actually I wrote a header for it, copied it from somewhere else :) So if I do a `systemctl list-unit-files`, only what shows as enabled is loaded at boot?

Comment: It should do, @Radu, yes; that'll be a mix of systemd and converted SysVInit services.

Comment: Or do I have to disable stuff from init.d too, since `systemctl disable` won't disable the init.d stuff also?

Comment: You can disable the init.d services the old-fashioned way, or use `systemd mask` as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159335/184220). Either should work.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try the systemd mask thing. It's pretty confusing stuff, I thought disable was supposed to do that by default.

Comment: Btw, is there a way to see a nice list of the services that start in init.d ?

Comment: @Radu `disable` does do that to systemd services... but the init.d services are generated *every* boot, so they get re-enabled every time.  To see everything that was generated, run `systemctl list-unit-files | grep generated`.

Comment: I did that, it comes empty, nothing found.

Comment: That's odd. Try looking in `rc.d`, and try running searching the `list-unit-files` output for some of those scripts with `grep` (just replace 'generated' with one of the script names). It's possible that some packages include *both* systemd and init.d scripts (in which case you only need to disable the systemd one, I should imagine).

Comment: My raspbian version is from march 2016 or so, I haven't updated since then (I bought it a while ago and it stayed unused until recently). So it's possible that it was a version that had both systems. Anyway, if it is both systems running, why would I only need to disable the systemd one?

Comment: The reason I started to investigate more was that even though I disable most of the services, it made virtually no difference in startup time. So I guess there is something strange going on.

Comment: Both *systems* never ran together, but the init.d files and systemd files are sometimes distributed together (see [here](https://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2016-pragmatic-debian-packaging) for example). If there's a systemd unit with the same name as the init.d script, and the systemd unit is disabled, it will 'block' the generated unit from being created.

Comment: And as for the issues with the delays, perhaps that merits a new question. `systemd-analyze critical-path` should at least narrow down the problems a little.

Comment: Thanks, I will open a new question, because I did a `systemd-analyze` blame and I don't like what I am seeing :D